# Marking Dictionary property as JSON column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
public class AuditLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(65536)]
    public IDictionary<string, object> AuditData { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible with EF Core 7 support for JSON columns to make this AuditData property to be JSON column? I am using SQL Server.

Comment: It will be tracked here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible but you have to configure it in the context not using the annotations.

You will need to add the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Json` then use the `HasJsonConversion` method in your `DbContext`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AuditLog>()
        .Property(e => e.AuditData)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(v, null))
        .HasColumnType("json");
}
```

Comment: Is it using System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: I don't think this is using the EF Core 7 JSON support. Will it work with the JSON queries?